# Недетерминированный алгоритм и побочные эффекты

Tags: алгоритм, теория-автоматов

Насколько я понимаю, *недетерминированный* алгоритм - это всего лишь абстрактная концепция и в реальности его не существует. Так как он не может быть решен за полиномиальное время на детерминированном (реальном) компьютере.

**Определение**: «*Недетерминированный алгоритм*» — это алгоритм, указывающий несколько путей обработки одних и тех же входных данных, — без какого-либо уточнения, какой именно вариант будет выбран.

**Тогда вопрос**: Может ли алгоритм с побочными эффектами считаться недетерминированным? Если да, то почему в таком случае его нельзя выполнить на реальном ПК?

**Приведу пример алгоритма**:

> На вход алгоритма подается строка - "Привет пользователь".
>   Далее пользователю предлагается выбрать один из 4-х пунктов меню,
>   при этом не указывается, какой пункт должен быть выбран.
>   На выходе - "Привет пользователь, вы выбрали n-ский пункт меню"

**Диллема**: Данный алгоритм полностью подходит под описание *недетерминированного алгоритма* и при этом решается за полиномиальное время на детерминированном компьютере.

1) Указываются несколько путей для обработки одних и тех же входных данных.
2) Невозможно заранее предсказать, какой из них будет выбран.
3) Любой результат верный, независимо от путей выбранных во время выполнения.
4) Результат работы алгоритма может быть разным, несмотря на то, что обрабатываются одни и те же входные данные.

Comment: Вычислительная сложность алгоритма и детерминированность — это абсолютно не взаимосвязанные вещи. не надо валить их в кучу.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что ввод пользователя - это тоже входные данные :)

Comment: Это пользователь у вас не детерминированный, а алгоритм детерминированный, полностью зависит от входных данных

Comment: @Harry на входе по условию, только строка. Других параметров нет.

Comment: @Mike недетерминированный пользователь? )) конечно, ведь он человек, а не робот. Просто так получилось, что он является составной частью алгоритма.

Comment: @Fat-Zer а я и не утверждаю, что это одно и тоже. Но согласитесь, одно от другого ещё как зависит. Иначе вы бы уже доказали, что P = NP и получили бы миллион долларов за решение одной из задач тысячелетия.

Comment: @Michael алгоритм выполняться на компьютере, пользователь частью компьютера не является и для алгоритма лишь внешний источник информации. И то что делает пользователь в любом случае для алгоритма является входными данными, хотя бы потому, что попадает в компьютер с помощью устройств ввода-вывода

Comment: @Mike а вы не путаете входные данные с побочными эффектами? Я конечно понимаю, что обычно такие алгоритмы пишутся в виде функции, которая принимает в качестве параметра выбор пользователя. Но это не тот случай. Здесь только один параметр, это константная строка.

Comment: @Michael Нет, не путаю. любые данные, которые не находятся в самой программе, а поступают извне являются входными (поэтому так и называются). Это вы путаете параметры функции и входные данные. Вы вызываете функцию, которая должна обработать данные из файла и отдать вам результат и передаете параметр "имя-файла", после чего функция читает этот файл и обрабатывает. Параметр один - имя, входные данные - имя файла и сами данные, прочитанные из файла. обратите внимание, если вы два раза вызываете функцию с одним именем и файл не менялся - результат один и тот же, следовательно она детерминированна

Comment: @Mike Допустим. Можно тогда в ответах, а не комментариях - пример, по-настоящему недетерминированного алгоритма? (не важно на чем, можно псевдокодом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Тогда вопрос: Может ли алгоритм с побочными эффектами считаться недетерминированным?

Тут путаница в понятиях: некий Алгоритм в строго математическом смысле эквивалентен некой машине Тьюринга и к нему в принципе не применимо такое понятие как «Побочные эффекты», т.к. мат. модель оной в принципе не предусматривает их существование. Так что вопрос в принципе не корректен.

С другой стороны в программировании есть ряд схожих терминов (неформальные определения):

- Детерминированная функция — функция, результат которой зависит только от входных данных, а не некоего внутреннего состояния, временных характеристик или чего-то ещё.
- Функция без побочных эффектов — очевидно.
- Чистая функция — детерминированная функция без побочных эффектов.

> Насколько я понимаю, недетерминированный алгоритм - это всего лишь абстрактная концепция и в реальности его не существует.

Конечно это всё не так, проблема в том, что произвольный недетерминированный алгоритм сложнее описать в обычном строгом псевдокоде.

Например, пусть задано множество А и число N. Задача: найти хотя бы одно a ∈ A такое что N делится на a.

Детерминированный алгоритм очевиден, проверить делится ли N на a₁, затем на  a₂ и т.д. Если a<sub>i</sub> делит N, то вернуть a<sub>i</sub>.

Недетерминированный алгоритм может делать тоже самое, но он не обязан устанавливать порядок, в котором проверяются элементы A, т.е. например, в зависимости от произвольных факторов a₁₂₅ может проверяться раньше, чем a₁. На практике, это можно описать, например, с помощью многопоточности или векторных операций.

Ключевое отличие не в том, что получается выигрыш в скорости за счёт распараллеливания действий и даже не в том, что результат может отличаться от запуска к запуску, а в том что **конкретный набор исполняемых действий и их порядок в точности не определены алгоритмом и входными данными**.

> Так как он не может быть решен за полиномиальное время на детерминированном (реальном) компьютере.

Совершенно бессмысленное утверждение... Это сравнение тёплого с мягким... Да многие тёплые предметы вроде котиков мягкие, но если заехал ногой по батарее она окажется отнюдь не мягкой. Так и тут, вычислительная сложность некоторых алгоритмов на недетерминированной машине может быть меньше, чем симуляция оных на детерминированной, но это не общее правило.

---

Все вышеприведённые умозаключения могут содержать ошибки и могут не являться истинной в последней инстанции...

Comment: Являются ли недетерминированный алгоритм и недетерминированная функция эквивалентными понятиями или это разные вещи? Алгоритм - это порядок действий, необходимый для достижения того или иного результата. Функцию, если сильно упрощать, можно определить также. Если детерминированные функции существуют, то к ним применимо и понятие - побочные эффекты. Таков ход моих рассуждений.

Comment: @Michael, нет, это понятия из разных областей... «алгоритм» — это понятие обще-математическое (в частности дискретной математики), а «функция» в данном случае ­— это понятие прикладного программирования, фактически синоним «подпрограмма» (со скидкой на терминологическую разницу конкретных языков)... Кроме того, дискретность алгоритма требует неизменности действий, а дискретность функции только независимости результата от исходных данных.

Comment: ИМХО даже не обязательно, чтобы дискретная функция реализовывала дискретный алгоритм (хотя в таком случае я бы потребовал от алгоритма единственность верного результата независимо от входных данных)... Кстати, терминология касательно «чистых-детерминированных» функций тоже плавает... например gcc называет `pure` функции без побочных эффектов, а чистые-детерминированные называет `const`, а в SQL принято называть только чистые функции детерминированными.